# Django try..except ValueError raised with no error

Tags: python, django, exception

I am trying to allow users to submit data optionally by including `try:...except ValueError:` to catch missing data, however the except is triggered even when all input values are included.

```
def sByInfo(request):
    print "\n \n NEW CALL"

    ranked = Ranked.objects.all()
    unranked = Unranked.objects.all()

    ranked_matches = [] # List for ranked institution matches
    unranked_matches = [] # List for unranked institution matches

    try:
        gpa = request.GET['gpa']
        gpa = float(gpa)
        print gpa
        pcat = request.GET['pcat']
        pcat = int(pcat)
        print pcat

        try:
            city = request.GET['city']
            state = request.GET['state']
            print "{}, {}".format(city, state)

            position = getPos(city, state)
            lati = Decimal(position['lat'])
            loni = Decimal(position['lon'])

            print "\n RANKED"
            for x in ranked:
                print x.name
                average_gpa = (x.gpa_expected + x.gpa_overall) / 2
                print average_gpa
                if gpa >= average_gpa:
                    print "GPA good"
                    if ranked_matches.index(x):
                        print "School already added"
                    else:
                        ranked_matches.append(x)
                        print "School added"
                else:
                    print "GPA too low"

                if pcat >= x.min_pcat:
                    if ranked_matches.index(x):
                        print "School already added"
                    else:
                        ranked_matches.append(x)
                else:
                    print "PCAT too low"

                lat = Decimal(x.lat)
                lon = Decimal(x.lon)
                difference = posDifference(lati, loni, lat, lon)
                print "Distance is {} miles".format(difference)

                if difference <= 150:
                    if ranked_matches.index(x):
                        print "School already added"
                    else:
                        ranked_matches.append(x)
                else:
                    print "School out of range"

            print "\n UNRANKED"
            for y in unranked:
                print y.name
                average_gpa = (y.gpa_expected + y.gpa_overall) / 2
                if gpa >= average_gpa:
                    if unranked_matches.index(y):
                        print "School already added"
                    else:
                        unranked_matches.append(y)
                else:
                    print "GPA too low"

                if pcat >= y.min_pcat:
                    if unranked_matches.index(y):
                        print "School already added"
                    else:
                        unranked_matches.append(y)
                else:
                    print "PCAT too low"

                lat = Decimal(y.lat)
                lon = Decimal(y.lon)
                difference = posDifference(lati, loni, lat, lon)
                print "Distance is {} miles".format(difference)

                if difference <= 150:
                    if unranked_matches.index(y):
                        print "School already added"
                    else:
                        unranked_matches.append(y)
                else:
                    print "School out of range"



        except ValueError: ## City or State was not submitted
            print "City or state missing"

            try:
                state = request.GET['state']
            except ValueError:
                print "City and state missing"

    except ValueError:
        return render('You must enter both GPA & PCAT scores')


    return render_to_response('results.html', {'ranked_matches' : ranked_matches, 'unranked_matches' : unranked_matches}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

The first `for` loop gets through a single iteration with no noticeable failures and then the first nested exception is raised returning the "City or state missing" message. I am confused as to why this exception is raised as all values were submitted.

I believe the issue must be somewhere in this `if` statement

```
if ranked_matches.index(x):
    print "School already added"
else:
    ranked_matches.append(x)
    print "School added"
```

All help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: wow, that's a pretty massive try-except block. What if something else raises `ValueError` there? Your error message might be misleading then

Comment: I did not consider that. That's a good point, but I'm still unsure of what would raise that error elsewhere

Comment: @haye321 trying to cast invalid string to integer or float will raise valueerror as i pointed out

Answer (score 1):

I dont think `ValueError` is robust enough,

if the data is incorrect data type

`int('test')`

it raises a `ValueError`, so its not a sufficient way to check for the presence of fields.

A more robust way is to use [djangos built in Forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/).  It will allow you to specify data types and required fields, and django will take care of the validation for you.

Comment: I have tried using django forms however I've found that their benefits are outweighed by difficulty integrating them with various front-end technologies.

Comment: @haye321 thats the cool part! you don't have to render html using the form you can solely use it on the backend to validate the incoming request data!!

Comment: That does sound cool but everything in the django forms documentation seems to indicate that you need to use them to render some HTML regardless.

Comment: @haye321 nope! thats a major aspect of it, but not required at all, its just a python class that takes a dictionary as its first param when you instantiate it and will run validation on that dictionary based on the fields you have specified in the class!! where the dictionary comes from doesn't matter, you can import the class and instantiate it yourself with request.GET, the inputs you have to pass to it need to match up with the fields it specifies, but still gives you the flexibilty to render whatever sort of html you want!

Comment: I'm giving this a try however I'm unsure of how to catch missing data? If you notice in my original question the logic varies slightly depending on what data was submitted (or omitted). My first thought is to stick with my `try...except`'s but now use `KeyError` instead of `ValueError`. Am I on the right track?

Comment: After trying this I discovered that `if ranked_matches.index(x):` was throwing a `ValueError` which is why the function exited prematurely. I'm not sure why this would do so because I tested this logic in the python shell and it ran fine.

Comment: Switching the `if` statement out for a `try...except ValueError` solved that.

Comment: 'KeyError' fails to catch the missing state parameters in my view however in the python shell it catches the exception as expected. No idea what could be the cause of this.